# How to get react-native run-ios to open in iTerm instead of Terminal on a macOS?

Tags: macos, react-native

How can somebody configure `react-native run-ios` to execute in iTerm instead of Terminal on OSX?  By default, it opens a new Terminal window, but Terminal doesn't work as well with my window manager as iTerm does.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

The packager is started by executing `open $PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command`, so whatever program is associated with *.command will be started. You can change the association:

- Open Finder
- Navigate to  $PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/scripts/ (or simply create an empty file with the .command extension anywhere)
- Right click launchPackager.command
- Press the OPTION key
- Under "Always open with..." you can select iTerm

Comment: just an update, I am running react-native `45.1` and now `lauchPackager.command` is under `$PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/packager/launchPackager.command`

Comment: another update, Im on react-native 55 and new location is `$PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command`

Answer (score 221):

Daniel's solution worked, but as soon as I reinstalled `node_modules` it stopped working.

To make the change persistent, right-click on `launchPackager.command` in `node_modules/react-native/scripts/` and choose Get Info…  Then change the "Open with:" section to iTerm, and click on `Change All…`

[image]

Comment: This is the real OG answer. Especially with React Native since removing node_modules is a common occurrence. Thanks @emmby